# Second section in collection view not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've got two arrays:

- feedbackImages - an array of UIImages
- feedbackVideos - an array of dictionarys which contain two keys, video url and thumbnail.

The problem I have is that all the cells for the second section (feedback videos) are not showing. I'm using a single image for every cell at the moment to try and get it to work.

When logging the count of the arrays, they both show they have items in them.

Here's my collection view code:

```
#pragma mark - Collection View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 1)
    {
        return [self.feedbackImages count];
    }
    else if (section ==2 )
    {
        return [self.feedbackVideos count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"86-camera.png"];

    cell.ImageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section start with index 0 not 1, change `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection` to:

```
if (section == 0) //<- change to 0
{
    return [self.feedbackImages count];
}
else if (section ==1 ) //<- change to 1
{
    return [self.feedbackVideos count];
}
```